555 as MOSFET driver always outputs high with input disconnected
I have been using a 555 timer as a MOSFET non-inverting driver for a few months now. It really is a signal amplifier for an Arduino Nano (which outputs 5 V) and it amplifies the signal into the gate of an n-channel 48 A MOSFET.
It works great unless the Arduino crashes. When that happens, the 555 output becomes HIGH on its pin 3. The same happens if pin 4 (reset/input) gets disconnected, so it's a bug related specifically to this kind of 555 setup. I found ways to avoid the Arduino crashing, but it would help a lot if the 555 pin 3 output would become LOW when its pin 4 (reset) is disconnected. So far, I tried a 4k7 resistor across the input, with no change.
The general system layout can be found here,
except, I use proper voltage regulator ICs for the Arduino and the 555.

I don't know how you would put a resistor "across the input", but have you tried a pull-up or pull-down resistor on the MCU pin?

What do you mean by "crashes"? Do you mean when the Arduino has no power, or do you mean when it freezes (stops executing code)? Is it ever possible for the Arduino to have power while the 555 does not, or vice versa?

Using a 555 as a push-pull output comparator in service of driving a gate of a mosfet is fairly clever. I have added it to my mental "bag of tricks" :)

Tim, a resistor across the input would be a resistor between pin 4 (reset, in this case input) and Ground.

Simón, what I meant by "crashes" was that it "freezes" indeed, it stops executing code and sends a random state on the output pin.

Kuba, I didn't come up with the idea. I just found it on a schematics website when searching for "555 as power MOSFET driver". The website in question is this https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/power/article/21795203/lm555-makes-inexpensive-power-driver

Below is the LTspice sim of a 555 driver circuit with an added NPN transistor on the Reset input, so the output goes low if the drive signal is removed.
The Rst input requires a resistor to ground no larger than 1kΩ to activate the Reset mode.
The S1 switch simulates the loss of input signal at 4.5ms (green trace), which then causes the 555 output (yellow trace) go go low.
Does that do what you want?


I think this npn transistor on the 555 input will do the trick, will implement it when I'll have the chance. I mean, if the simulator says so, it must be so. I selected the green ✔️ , it is used for choosing an answer, right?

Sadly, if the Arduino is "crashing", and outputting a random high, and you don't employ some other means of testing the state of the Arduino (such as a watchdog) there is no way for any external circuitry to determine whether that high is intentional or not.
A physical disconnection of the 555's reset pin can be pulled low, though, using a resistor between reset and ground. The only caveat is that the reset input is not very high impedance, and this pull-down resistor should be small, probably much less than 4.7kΩ.
Another reason for keeping the pull-down resistance \$R\$ small, is to overcome the Arduino's internal pull-up resistance, in the case where the crash results in the I/O pin being configured as an input, with internal pull-up enabled. In fact, you should aim to use an external pull-down calculated to sink as much current as the Arduino can source during normal operation, which is 20mA continuous. That would keep the reset pin potential as low as possible:
$$ R = \frac{5V}{20mA} \approx 270\Omega $$
If the Arduino output is being reconfigured during a crash, the crash is the result of a severe disruption to its internal state, and is not some minor glitch. The most likely reasons for this are inadequate power-supply decoupling, and ill-considered routing of wiring carrying large current transients, such as the wiring to the MOSFET's load.
Make sure that the load's current carrying wires are kept close and parallel (or twisted together), are as short as possible, and are physically routed as far from any low-current signal paths as possible. This will mitigate magnetically induced currents elsewhere. If the Arduino's 5V is derived from the same 12V source used by the load, make sure that both elements have their own pair of independent supply wires right up to the terminals of the 12V source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Supply decoupling capacitors are not optional. The Arduino probably has adequate decoupling already on-board, but there's no harm in placing a ceramic 100nF capacitor across it's own supply, as close to its supply pins as possible.
Even the 555, which is momentarily sourcing and sinking 200mA into/out of the MOSFET gate at each transition, needs its supply decoupling. A ceramic 1μF capacitor across the supply pins near the IC should suffice, or a paralleled pair of ceramic 100nF and electrolytic 1μF.
The MOSFET and its load are the most likely cause of power supply perturbations, and is of special concern since it shares a supply with the 555. If your Arduino 5V supply is also derived from this same 12V source, then you have even more reason to keep that 12V as clean as possible. It will require significant, low ESR capacitance nearby and across its supply, but without knowing load current, it's not possible to say how much.
